# Sampling using conditional probability table

Tags: r, simulation, probability, sampling

I am trying to simulate certain discrete variable depicting "true state of the world" (say, "red", "green" or "blue") and its indicator, somewhat imperfectly describing it.

```
r_names <- c("real_R", "real_G", "real_B")
```

Lets say I have some prior belief about distribution of "reality" variable, which I will use to sample it.

```
r_probs <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
set.seed(100)
reality <- sample(seq_along(r_names), 10000, prob=r_probs, replace = TRUE)
```

Now, let's say I have conditional probability table that stipulates the value of indicator given each of the "realities"

```
ri_matrix <- matrix(c(0.7, 0.3, 0, 
                      0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 
                      0.05,0.15,0.8), byrow=TRUE,nrow = 3)
dimnames(ri_matrix) <- list(paste("real", r_names, sep="_"),
                        paste("ind", r_names, sep="_"))

ri_matrix

>#            ind_R ind_G ind_B
># real_Red    0.70  0.30   0.0
># real_Green  0.20  0.60   0.2
># real_Blue   0.05  0.15   0.8
```

Since `base::sample()` is not vectorized for `prob` argument, I have to:

```
sample_cond <- function(r, rim){
  unlist(lapply(r, function(x) 
    sample(seq_len(ncol(rim)), 1, prob = rim[x,], replace = TRUE)))
 }
```

Now I can sample my "indicator" variable using the conditional probability matrix

```
set.seed(200)
indicator <- sample_cond(reality, ri_matrix)
```

Just to make sure the distributions turned out as expected:

```
prop.table(table(reality, indicator), margin = 1)

 #>        indicator
 #> reality          1          2          3
 #>       1 0.70043610 0.29956390 0.00000000
 #>       2 0.19976124 0.59331476 0.20692400
 #>       3 0.04365278 0.14400401 0.81234320
```

Is there a better (i.e. more idiomatic and/or efficient) way to sample a discrete variable conditioned on another discrete random variable?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Mr.Flick, this is at least 50x faster, because it reuses probability vectors instead of repeated subsetting of the conditional probability matrix.

```
sample_cond_group <- function(r, rim){
il <- mapply(function(x,y){sample(seq(ncol(rim)), length(x), prob = y, replace = TRUE)}, 
       x=split(r, r),
       y=split(rim, seq(nrow(rim))))
unsplit(il, r)
}
```

Comment: interestingly, using a for loop inside your original function runs about 28-29% faster on average than the `unlist` wrapped `lapply`. So something like this: `mm[i] <- sample(1:3, 1, prob=rim[r[i],])` in the loop is speedier. Whodathunkit?

Answer (score 1):

You can be a bit more efficient by drawing all the random samples per group with a split/combine type strategy. That might look something like this

```
simFun <- function(N, r_probs, ri_matrix) {
  stopifnot(length(r_probs) == nrow(ri_matrix))
  ind <- sample.int(length(r_probs), N, prob = r_probs, replace=TRUE)
  grp <- split(data.frame(ind), ind)
  unsplit(Map(function(data, r) {
    draw <-sample.int(ncol(ri_matrix), nrow(data), replace=TRUE, prob=ri_matrix[r, ])
    data.frame(data, draw)
    }, grp, as.numeric(names(grp))), ind)
}
```

Than you can call with

```
simFun(10000, r_probs, ri_matrix)
```